# Pass parameter with a space in prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

The prepared statement that gets generated dynamically from my PHP (as an example) looks like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(exuid) as result_count FROM full_db3 WHERE `Age Range` = :Age Range
```

`Age Range` is one of my column names.

The problem here is that having the space in between "Age" and "Range" in my parameter, but I'm not sure how to handle this. The query is generated dynamically like so (only relevant code shown):

```
$all_attributes = $_POST['attris'];
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(exuid) as result_count FROM {$table}";
    $any_condition = false;
    foreach($all_attributes as $key=>$val) {

       if (!empty($val) && in_array($key,$validKeys)) {
         if ($any_condition) {
           $sql .= ' AND `'.$key.'` = :'.$key;
         } else {
           $sql .= ' WHERE `'.$key.'` = :'.$key;
           $any_condition = true;
         }
       }
    }




 $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);

    foreach($all_attributes as $key=>$val) {

   if (!empty($val)  && in_array($key,$validKeys)) {
     $stmt ->bindValue(':'.$key, $val, PDO::PARAM_STR);
   }
}

$stmt->execute();
```

If I change my column name in the DB to `Age_Range` everything works perfectly fine. For a number of reasons, I'd like to be able to exclude that underscore, as I display my column names in a select and all the underscores look terrible.

Comment: Couldn't you just replace spaces with underscores on the rhs of the conditions when you are building the query? or do parameter names have to match field names in that php mysql library?

Comment: `":" . str_replace(' ', '_', $key)`

Comment: Couldn't you just fix the schema

Comment: I concur with @Drew though; it is best to have your field names tailored for use in queries, rather than output. You can always alias fields in results when they will actually be displayed.

Comment: of course it won't happen cuz there are a thousand columns like that :> But how many hours do we spend wondering if order by order will work, and back tick everything. It's nuts

Comment: you can use ticks `\`` just as you did just before it.

Comment: @u_mulder This will put an underscore back into the query. Correct? If so, then this won't match my schema, which is to have all column names with spaces instead of underscores

Comment: @Fred-ii- I thought of this and tried a few things, but not sure where to put them for the parameter part.

Comment: @Drew I'm all for fixing the schema. I would like to have all my column names NOT have an underscore. However, when I do that, the script in my question breaks. So, I'm looking to fix the script to work with this new schema.

Comment: the thing is, you have control over that bind; so I suggest you don't try and re-invent anything here.

Comment: Why don't you use `?` as placeholder?

Comment: @Fred-ii- For example, this doesn't work: `SELECT COUNT(exuid) as result_count FROM full_db3 WHERE `Age Range` = `:Age Range```

Comment: just wondering how fred did that in comments with the ```. Above my paygrade. Especially after the $20 (CAD) I owe him.

Comment: I'll settle for 2x 10 ;-) @Drew we'll be "kit" after that lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using my idea, and copying syntax from u_mulder's comment, this should work?

```
$all_attributes = $_POST['attris'];
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(exuid) as result_count FROM {$table}";
$any_condition = false;
foreach($all_attributes as $key=>$val) {

   if (!empty($val) && in_array($key,$validKeys)) {
     if ($any_condition) {
       $sql .= ' AND `'.$key.'` = :'.str_replace(' ', '_', $key);
     } else {
       $sql .= ' WHERE `'.$key.'` = :'.str_replace(' ', '_', $key);
       $any_condition = true;
     }
   }
}
```

It leaves the field names as is, and only changes the parameter names.

But this

```
$stmt ->bindValue(':'.$key, $val, PDO::PARAM_STR)
```

will probably need changed to this as well

```
$stmt ->bindValue(':'.str_replace(' ', '_', $key), $val, PDO::PARAM_STR)
```

Comment: This isn't working for some reason. I suspect it's because of how the query is executed. Check out my edited answer that shows how this is done. I guess it really doesn't matter if the parameter is the same name as the key, as long as the right value is passed.

Comment: @jonmrich yeah, since the parameter name changed, that will need to as well. See edit.

Comment: Worked perfectly with the edit! Thank you. Now...can you tell me why this works so I don't end up asking the same question again? I wouldn't have thought it would work like this (with or without the edit).

Comment: @jonmrich The `:` prefixed portions are your parameter names; the ` enclosed ones are the field names. Your parameter names could just as easily be `:p1`, `:p2`, etc... By `prepare`ing, you make it so the query only needs parsed once (though in this case that has no benefit; the parameters make you arguments safer by doing all the special character escaping for you.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. Definitely a lot more to learn for me here.